# Chef update certain user's .bashrc

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to update certain users .bashrc JAVA_HOME environment variable after installing JDK.  I get this strange error that I don't understand.  Here's the block of code in question.

```
node['etc']['passwd'].each do |user, data|
  only_if {data['uid'] > 9000}
  jdk_dir_array = Dir.entries('/usr/java/').select {|entry| File.directory? File.join('/usr/java/',entry) and !(entry =='.' || entry == '..') }
  jdk_dir_name = jdk_dir_array.shift
  file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("#{data['dir']}/.bashrc")
  file.search_file_replace( /JAVA_HOME=.*/,"JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/#{jdk_dir_name}")
  file.write_file
end
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
No resource or method named `only_if' for `Chef::Recipe "install_jdk"'
```

I don't understand why it thinks "only_if" is a method of the recipe when I declare it inside of the node.each block.

i should point out that if I put this in a ruby_block and hardcode the path to a single user's home directory the code works as expected.  I'm trying to update multiple users and that's where I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`only_if` is a method you use on a resource, not in either a recipe or inside the block of a `ruby_block`. What you want is something more like like:

```
node['etc']['passwd'].each do |user, data|
  ruby_block "edit #{user} bashrc" do
  only_if { data['uid'] > 9000 }
  block do
    jdk_dir_array = Dir.entries('/usr/java/').select {|entry| File.directory? File.join('/usr/java/',entry) and !(entry =='.' || entry == '..') }
    jdk_dir_name = jdk_dir_array.shift
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("#{data['dir']}/.bashrc")
    file.search_file_replace( /JAVA_HOME=.*/,"JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/#{jdk_dir_name}")
    file.write_file
  end
end
```

I really recommend not doing this though. Check out the [`line` cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/line) for a more refined way to approach this, or consider having Chef manage the whole file via a `template` resource.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is, this recipe gets called after I've updated the JDK so a template didn't seem appropriate.  I greatly appreciate the help and the link.

Comment: You would probably want to have a standard shell init template and then create something like `~/.env.d/` where you can drop extra files in which all get sourced by that main template.